# what is the difference between dynamic and static fetching in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, static

I am a new hibernate user. I have been reading the user guife provided by this site
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching
they started talking about static and dynamic fetching without an introduction to those to words. What is static and dynamic fetching?

Answer (score 0):

In ORM (Object Relational Mapping), fetching is how you load related data into memory...

Assuming the example 390 of the link that you provided, when you load an employee from the persistence layer, you two have options about the Employee's Department:

1) Either to instruct the ORM (hibernate) to load the Department information as soon as the Employee is loaded, or

2) To instruct the ORM to load the associated department only when it gets need it; i.e., when you call `employee.getDepartment().getName()`;

Depending of your needs, you will choose once of these two options. In order to tell the ORM what option did you choose, you use static fetching or dynamic fetching...

Static fetching is done through annotations (or XML), and it considered static because once you write it, it cannot be changed in runtime... (Beware, relational annotations like `@ManyToOne` impose a Fetch EAGER Strategy by default)

Dynamic fetching, is done through programmatic configurations or queries in runtime, allowing you to dictate when (a how) a related data will be loaded into memory...